# xCode shows 0x0000000 for a created object

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

See this picture [image: img]

How can this be possible? I clearly create the object, why Xcode shows `0x000000`? 
The property itself is defined like this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IndicatorsOnChartViewController 
                                 *IndicatorsOnChartController;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might be running into a bug Xcode 4.3.x has with the LLDB debugger not showing proper values. Until there’s a fix, you could resort to using the GDB debugger, by editing the scheme for your executables as shown:

[image]